# How to force a Custom Post Type template by filename

Tags: templates, single

I made a Custom post type called CPT and most of it works fine. I made a 'single-CPT.php' file in the theme's folder to be the template for each CPT page.  When I click on the permalink that I see while editing each CPT, the page loads using the 404 error template.  I don't usually use the generated page so I don't know if I am doing this right, but I researched and found that Wordpress will locate the 'single-{custom post}.php' file in the theme folder and generate the page using that template.  Why is my wordpress not doing that?

Comment: Did you try visiting the permalinks page under Settings? By visiting it, the "cache" gets flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you likely need to do a flush re-write.  go to settings/permalinks in the dashboard and click save.  You'll be good to go.  In the future you can add this directly to your CPT plugin.  I would suggest getting a bit more creative with your naming though so you don't have conflicts later.

Comment: this is just for my own learning, but why did that do it?

Comment: In simple words: By visiting that page, you refresh the permalinks in Wordpress. After creating a custom post type, all the URL's need to be refreshed, otherwise they will give a 404 error as if they never existed.

Comment: @pim is right.  You need to tell wordpress to check that you made new links.  In the future, it's better to do this within your plugin.  You can set a function to flush the rules when you initialize the plugin.  That way you don't have to do it manually each time.

Comment: oh hey, yeah,  Do I just add it to my functions file?

Comment: how are you creating the cpt? you can't put it in the function file.  put it it the plugin file so it is called on init of the plugin.

Comment: its ok, they solved it, and the CPT is part of the theme.